# Adding Multiple values to a single row in a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add multiple column values to a single row in python, i have tried this:

```
with open (filename,'a') as golds:
        golds.write(self.BOBtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.Whompstextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.SSLtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.BITDWtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.SSLtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.LLLtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.HMCtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.DDDtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.BITFStextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.BLJtextbox.get())
        golds.write(self.BITStextbox.get())
```

However this adds all the data to a single row and column whereas i want all each write statement in a different column, any ideas?

Edit: just to be clearer, the value outputted into the csv file is put all into one cell:
1254567891011
instead of:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, what are the return values of calls to `.get()`, can you give an example? What do you get in the output file and what did you expect / need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no commas in all of the text boxes string, have you tried adding comma between each expected column?

```
with open (filename,'a') as golds:
    golds.write(self.BOBtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.Whompstextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.SSLtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.BITDWtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.SSLtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.LLLtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.HMCtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.DDDtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.BITFStextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.BLJtextbox.get())
    golds.write(",")
    golds.write(self.BITStextbox.get())
```

Alternatively, you can use python `csv` built-in library instead

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([
        self.BOBtextbox.get(),
        self.Whompstextbox.get(),
        self.SSLtextbox.get(),
        self.BITDWtextbox.get(),
        self.SSLtextbox.get(),
        self.LLLtextbox.get(),
        self.HMCtextbox.get(),
        self.DDDtextbox.get(),
        self.BITFStextbox.get(),
        self.BLJtextbox.get(),
        self.BITStextbox.get()
    ])
```